# Button triggered Admob interstitial ads not working in second time click

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I setup the Admob Interstitial ads triggered in a button to get following result,

1. Click button and appear interstitial ads
2. After close the ads,and proceed to play video
3. And click back button and get back to previous
   activity

Ads is showing perfectly and proceed to video after the ads showing, But the problem is If I click again to button after clicked back button, it's reproduce the app crash and stop the app. I was googling about the problem, but still out of luck.

Here is my code that integrate the ads,

```js
img_ply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_intertestial_id));
    mInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
     @Override
     public void onAdLoaded() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onAdLoaded();
      if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
       mInterstitial.show();
       mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
         super.onAdClosed();
                                    

         Intent inttv = new Intent(SingleChannelActivity.this, TvPlay.class);
         inttv.putExtra("url", ChannelUrl);
         startActivity(inttv);
        }

       });
      }else{
       super.onAdLoaded();


      }
     }

    });

   }
  });
```

Comment: how did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try using "mInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());" again in your onAdClosed() method.